# How to format the value of a variable using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So my issue is that google analytic takes the value of $1,000 (or any value with a comma) and changes it to $1.000 so it's reporting incorrect values.

So i figured what I needed to do was create a `customVariable  = [[S120:dc:giftAmount]]`, and then change the format of the value of the variable to remove the comma,
and then pass the variable back into google analytic

the amount varies depending on the $ amounts received from whomever makes the donations.

so in the GA code it appears as this:

`revenue:'[[S120:dc:giftAmount]]',`

that is where I would place the formatted variable that would pass through to GA. the data is being pulled from [[S120:dc:giftAmount]]

I thought if I did something like this, it might work:

```
<script>
    var formatDollar = '[[S120:dc:giftAmount]]';
        formatDollar.split(",").join("");
    var dollarAmt = formatDollar.split(",").join("");

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-1039484-49');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  id: '[[S120:dc:transactionID]]',
  affiliation: '[[S120:dc:donationFormName]]',

      revenue: dollarAmt,
      category: '[[S120:dc:giftType]]',
      currency: 'CAD'
    });
    ga('ecommerce:send');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. Does my own javascript code have to be in a separate script tag and then used in GA's script tag?

thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you also show the rest of your ecommerce code relative to where your above code is? You would need to be modifying the data that is being used in the ecommerce object.

Comment: @nyuen I've edited the post, included the full GA code.

Comment: why do you send the string revenue: 'dollarAmt',  instead of the variable with revenue: dollarAmt,

Comment: @progysm I thought because I'm taking the string from dc:giftAmount that it would be assigned to the variable dolllarAmt as a string so I would need to write it that way. Is this what is causing me issues? I will remove it and see if that works

Comment: `revenue` should be a string `'123.44'` or number `22.99` (cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions). Also, the placement of your code is fine.

Comment: @nyuen I don't quite understand what you mean. So my code should work?

Comment: `dollarAmt` should evaluate to either a string or number as I mentioned above. Right now you are just passing in the string "dollarAmt", which doesn't get evaluated to what you really intend it to be. So instead of passing in `'dollarAmt'`, you should just pass the variable `dollarAmt`. I don't immediately see anything else wrong with the code.

Comment: oh i see! okay so i have changed that I'm just waiting on the team to get back to me to see if it works now. Thank you nyuen.

Comment: @nyuen Hi there, so we've run some test transactions, and it's pulling in the number of transactions but it isn't showing us the revenue. So I'm lost as to what is happening.

Comment: What does your updated code look like?

Comment: I removed the quotes around `revenue: dollarAmt` and ran the script, but it still didn't pull the revenue amount.

Comment: @nyuen hi! sorry, i took a look at the code I gave them and for some reason they re-added the quotes around the variable for revenue, so i removed it and we're receiving the $ amount. Now to wait and see until someone makes a 1000 dollar donation lol can you please post your response as the answer so I can mark it solved. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dollarAmt` should evaluate to either a string or number. Right now you are just passing in the string `"dollarAmt"`, which doesn't get evaluated to what you really intend it to be. So instead of passing in `"dollarAmt"`, you should just pass the *variable* `dollarAmt`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.